What is this 80's or 90's A.I. car movie?
Okay I watched this when I was quite young, it was on VHS so pretty much late 80's early 90's.
It is about this scientist that builds an artificially intelligent car. The car at the beginning is a blue ordinary sedan that get's destroyed fighting bad guys or so I remember.
The car is resurrected as a red sports car, maybe a dodge viper or something similar.
The thing I vividly remember is that the new car had a virtual reality-type windshield. It could display all sorts of info on the windshield and pick targets by eye tracking or something similar.
And no, it's not Knight rider. Any ideas?

Knight Rider 2000, the 1991 movie sequel to the Knight Rider series.  It has the blue sedan:

Eventually, Michael is able to reactivate K.I.T.T.'s logic module and
  temporarily installs him in the dashboard of his 1957 Chevy Bel-Air.
  K.I.T.T. protests his vintage look, but it is the best Michael can do
  for him under the circumstances.

It has the car die by drowning:

The two are easily chased down by the police when they try to get away
  in K.I.T.T.'s classic car body which isn't the indestructible shell he
  once had. K.I.T.T. decides to evade capture by driving off a pier into
  the harbor where he quickly sinks to the bottom. Michael and Shawn are
  momentarily kept safe inside the "air tight" driving compartment but
  K.I.T.T. isn't so lucky as water seeps in and shorts out his
  circuitry.

It has the car "resurrected" into the red sports car:

Michael later returns, and secretly retrofits the Knight 4000 with
  K.I.T.T.'s A.I. (though, the AI is still called "KITT" because the
  KIFT was the previous AI ) and Maddock & Shawn find out after the
  retrofit is complete. KITT gets used to his new body and the vehicle's
  advanced features, such as a heads up virtual reality display in the
  windshield, an ultrasound gun, thermal generator, and arominometer to
  name a few.



YES!!! That's it! For some reason I couldn't remember the Hoff in it, so thought it couldn't possibly have anything to do with the Kight rider saga! But yeap, that's the one. Thanks so much!
